# How Configurable Product's option rendered in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Actually I am creation a custom product view page fore understanding the rendering of product view

I have created controller like this

```
namespace Tasks\BulkAdd\Controller\Index;
class Vivek extends Action{
    ...
    public function execute()
    {
        $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
        $product = $this->repository->get($sku);
        $this->registry->register('product', $product);
        $this->registry->register('current_product', $product);

        $result = $this->pageFactory->create();
        return $result;

    }
}
```

In my layout file "bulkadd_index_vivek.xml" I have copied all the content of "catalog_product_view.xml"

My link is show like "http://10.16.16.188/magento/wholesaler/bulkadd/index/vivek/sku/24-MB01-1"

For simple products, It is working fine and showing all customisation options of product. Take a look bellow

[image]

but for Configurable products, It is not making configuration. See the output

[image]

I found that two Blocks are taking product from registry with key "product" and "current_product". That's why I set them in my controller.

Please tell what else i need to set from my controller to get product Configurations?

Thank You